# Kohen Gadol Teffilin

Tags: tefilin, kohen-gadol

While conducting the avodah in the Beis Hamikdash, in addition to the 8 garments that made up the Kohen Gadol's uniform, he would also wear his Tefillin.

Why isn't the Tefillin considered a 9th garment?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29575/759 see tosfot to zvachim there

Comment: @DoubleAA Thank you for linking that post. That is an interesting discussion.

Comment: All of the Kohanim wore tefillin, not just the Kohen Gadol.

Comment: Rashi (Bavli eiruvin 95b) classifies it as an ornament (vs clothing proper) altho I'm unsure as to why it is all that diff than the tzitz

Comment: @Nahum thank you for that Rashi. Regarding tzitzs, i dont belive they wore tzitzs while wearing their uniform.

Comment: Lol I'm referring to the ציץ not ציצית altho now that you bring it up maybe they did put tzitzis on the bigdei kehunah if any qualified for them

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [tefillin isn't a garment](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Zevachim.19b.1.1). Second, it's not a garment specifically for the Avodah, so I'm not surprised it's not listed.

Comment: For related issues of ייתור בגדים (the flip side of מחוסר בגדים) see here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105506/kohen-with-eyeglasses

Comment: @EraserX thanks for adding the source! Great edit.

Comment: tefilin isn't garment 
this is why we are not blessing them with shechyanou when we receive new ones

Comment: @L770 I think the reason for not making a shehecheyanu might be because it's leather, and we don't make a shehecheyanu on something that requires killing an animal.